ADB (read ECONNRESET) when connecting on bluestacks
Ok so, i found a title bot for the game of Rise Of Kingdoms on github(https://github.com/daniellwdb/rok-title-keeper) and im trying to run it. But i get the error below. I have my adb port open and it’s “127.0.0.1:5555”. I have tried putting the ip:port manually but the program stuck at const [device]. Can anyone help me resolve this ?
Part of the code:
const blueStacksConfig = await readFile(
  join("C:\\", "ProgramData", "BlueStacks_nxt", "bluestacks.conf"),
  "utf-8"
);

const BLUESTACKS_ADB_PORT = blueStacksConfig
  .split("\n")
  .find(
    (key) => key.startsWith("bst.instance") && key.includes("status.adb_port")
  )
  ?.split("=")
  .at(1)
  ?.replaceAll('"', "");

if (!BLUESTACKS_ADB_PORT) {
  throw new Error("Could not find BlueStacks adb port.");
}

await execAsync('".\\platform-tools\\adb.exe" kill-server');

await execAsync(
  `".\\platform-tools\\adb.exe" connect localhost:${BLUESTACKS_ADB_PORT}`
);

const adb = new AdbClient({
  bin: join(process.cwd(), "platform-tools", "adb.exe"),
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 5037,
});

const [device] = await adb.map((device) => device);

if (!device) {
  throw new Error("adb could not connect to a device.");
}

const logger = pino({ name: config.get("name") });

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log:
    process.env["NODE_ENV"] !== "production"
      ? ["query", "info"]
      : ["error", "warn"],
});

await prisma.$connect();

const discord = new DiscordClient({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds],
});

and the output before crashing is:
prisma: info Starting a sqlite pool with 9 connections. Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSwrap.onStreamRead (node: internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)

As far as I know adb is a plaintext connection, without an TLS option. Therefore the error message has nothing to do with your adb code posted here. Why don't you debug the video and execute it step by step hm see where the error occurs?

The thing is the code is working fine and doing all connections, until it’s time to create the bot that this error occurs, but i think it is not the bot which cause this. What do u suggest to do ?
